# GIT - Compare new version with commit version

Tags: git, compare

I have a file commited in my master branch on git and i produce a new one. 
I want to compare my new local version with commited version with a
specific software :

`./software [option] [myLocalVersion.file] [commitedVersion.file]`

How can i do that?

Thanks.

Comment: "specific software" means that you won't use the difftool defined in your git configuration for this specific case or you don't know that you can do that? For a comparison using the configured tool, the command is as simple as `git diff yourFile` (this will compare the current modified version with the version before you modify it)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add something like this to your `.gitconfig`:

```
[difftool "software"]
        cmd = software <my options> "$LOCAL" "$REMOTE"
```

Then use `git difftool <my file>`.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
git show <commit>:<filename> | ./software localfile -
```